# How do I make Plug.ErrorHandler and other Plug work at the same time?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I noticed that the response generated by `send_resp` in the `handle_errors` callback of `Plug.ErrorHandler` does not pass through other Plugs.

For example, I build a JSON response in `handle_error`. But this JSON response won't pass my `JSONHeaderPlug` and `CORSPlug`. This has brought a lot of trouble.

Specific symptoms such as the lack of these essential HTTP headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: 
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Is there a way to let the response in `handle_error` pass through other Plugs in the same order as the normal response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this is the case (I thought all the plugs before the error will be applied, but I did reproduce your situation). Still you can put all the plugs in a module and call it yourself. Remember you should do as little as possible in the `handle_errors` callback, because one of the plugs might be the reason for the error.

```
defmodule ApplySomePlug do
  use Plug.Builder

  plug(CORSPlug)
  plug(:put_custom_header)

  def put_custom_header(conn, _) do
    Plug.Conn.put_resp_header(conn, "foo", "bar")
  end
end
```

and to use it

```
def handle_errors(conn, _) do
  opts = ApplySomePlug.init(nil)
  conn = ApplySomePlug.call(conn, opts)

  Phoenix.Controller.json(conn, %{error: "something bad happened"})
end
```